# is there any way to access all references to given object?

Tags: php, oop, reflection, variables, reference

anyone has idea if and how is it possible to destroy / change php object which is referenced in many places? unset obviously destroys only one reference, and sometimes tracing all references manually is not an option. Any ideas? Maybe there is something i am missing in Reflection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice answer Mark, but i'm not sure how this would work:

**First Diagram:**

```
<?php

$obj = "foo";
$a = $obj;
$b = $obj;
$c = $obj;

$c = NULL;
unset( $c );
var_dump( $a, $b, $c );
```

**Results:**

```
string(3) "foo"
string(3) "foo"
NULL
```

**Second Diagram:**

```
<?php

$obj = "foo";
$wrapper =& $obj;
$a = $wrapper;
$b = $wrapper;
$c = $wrapper;

$c = NULL;
unset( $c );
var_dump( $a, $b, $c );
```

**Results:**

```
string(3) "foo"
string(3) "foo"
NULL
```

**Correct Way:**

```
<?php

$obj = "foo";
$a =& $obj;
$b =& $obj;
$c =& $obj;

$c = NULL;
var_dump( $a, $b, $c );
```

**Results:**

```
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

**Explanation:**

> You need to reference your variables
>   $a,$b,$c to the memory address of
>   $obj, this way when you set $c to
>   NULL, this will set the actual memory address
>   to NULL instead of just the reference.

Comment: although pragmatically, when setting a reference to an object, it is not always easier to set it using a reference.

Answer (score 6):

No but you can use an extra level of indirection instead. Currently you have this:

```
 a    b     c           a    b    (unset)
  \   |    /             \   |
   \  |   /    -->        \  |
    object                 object
```

Instead you can do this:

```
 a    b     c           a    b     c
  \   |    /             \   |    /
   \  |   /    -->        \  |   /
   wrapper                (unset)
      |
      |
   object
```